# Сan't return the thymeleaf template

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

The problem is that instead of outputting a thymeleaf template the browser displays a page with the word "login". I think it has to do with the configuration but I can't find the error. Probably someone knows how to solve this problem

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  autoconfigure:
    exclude: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration;
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/getyourhotel
    password: *password*
    username: root
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8InnoDBDialect
    generate-ddl: true
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    properties:
      hibernate:
        globally_quoted_identifiers: true
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
        format_sql: true
  sql:
    init:
      mode: never
      continue-on-error: false
  thymeleaf:
    prefix: classpath:/templates/
    suffix: .html
    mode: HTML
    cache: false

application:
  title: getyourhotel
  version: 1.0
```

**Dependencies from pom.xml**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Controller**

```
    @PostMapping("/login")
       public String login(@RequestBody @Valid User user, Model model) {
         UserDTO userDTO = userService.findUser(user);
         model.addAttribute("user", userDTO);
         return "login";
        }
```

**Project tree**
[*here*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUPpJ.png)

Comment: First you need a `@GetMapping` which returns `"login"` to load and show login page. Then a `PostMapping` to process data posted from the login form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't the controller set to @RestController?

In case of @RestController, the login string in return is returned as body.

In that case, please change it to @Controller.